# (android studio mobile app project) Errors: package com.google.ads does not exist

Tags: java, android

i recently got into a game project (reskinning) and couldn't compile on android studio ==> 9 errors;

```
error: package com.google.ads does not exist// import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
error: package com.google.ads does not exist// import com.google.ads.AdSize;
error: package com.google.ads does not exist// import com.google.ads.AdView;
error: cannot find symbol class AdView// AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
error: cannot find symbol class AdView// AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
error: cannot find symbol variable AdSize// AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
error: cannot find symbol class AdRequest// AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
error: cannot find symbol class AdRequest// AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specify google play services in gradle.build?

```
Compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```